# How can see find process that have pages swapped out?

Tags: swap, process

I would like to know which processes have pages swapped out. htop only show virtual memory which may or may not be paged out. Are there any tool that are more refined than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is going to be

> /proc/$PID/smaps
>   /proc/$PID/status
>   /proc/$PID/stat

replace $PID with the pid from ps, top, or htop.

There is also `/proc/meminfo` which has some general info.

Based on comments this might help:

`for i in *; do cat /proc/$i/status | grep "Name:"; cat /proc/$i/status | grep "VmSwap:"; echo ""; done`

It will have to be run as root. From the /proc/ directory.

Comment: I have never used it but smem is supposed to good, though it focuses on other bits of info. May help you though.

Comment: Thanks... /proc/$PID/status is helping... Would be nice if there would be a tool that only shows the processes that use swap instead of having to search through all

Comment: added a sample command that may help you. It's not pretty, but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks coteyr.. I have written already something similar. I probably will build something more succinct later.

 --- egrep -e "VmSwap|Name" /proc/*/status